# copy cp using pg_dump + pg_restore, getting error:

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Here are my commands:

```
db_conn_str="${db_prefix}@${db_host}/${db_name}"

pg_dump -w --schema-only --clean --create \
   -U dev -d "$db_conn_str" > "$tmp_folder/dev_dump.sql"

psql -h localhost -U postgres -1 -f "$tmp_folder/dev_dump.sql"
```

I am getting this error:

> pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table
>   cp_users
>
> pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE public.cp_users IN
>   ACCESS SHARE MODE

does anyone know how to mitigate that error? My goal is to copy a database from a remote db to my local db.

Comment: Are you doing this pg_dump on production environment? You have problems with `LOCK`. This means that another connection are using for a long time this table and not unlocking there.

Comment: Try to add a user that have access to the database. Like 'pg_dump -d db -U dbuser -h hostname > db.dmp'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give user `dev` the right to `SELECT` from all tables or use a different user.